# Allied telesis AT-9000/24 factory reset

Tags: switch

I just got a Allied telesis AT-9000/24, and after connecting it and getting to web interface I noticed that the username and password has been changed. So is there a reset switch on the inside or do I need one of those rs-232 to usb convertors to access the terminal and reset it through that way?

The only things I noticed that could be connected as a reset switch said GND and RJ4. None of them sound like a reset switch to me and don't want to brick the switch by connecting them via a wire.

If required I can post some pictures of the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any hardware method to reset the software to the factory default. According to the manual, you will need to connect to the switch and reset it through software:

> ## Returning the AT-S84 Management Software to the Factory Default Values
>
> ---
>
> This procedure returns all AT-S84 management software parameters to  their default values and deletes all tagged and VLANs on the
>   switch. The  AT-S84 management software default values are listed in
>   Appendix A,  ”AT-S84 Default Settings” on page 319.
>
> ---
>
> **Caution**
>
> This procedure causes the switch to reboot. The switch does not
>   forward network traffic during the reboot process. Some network
>   traffic may be lost.
>
> ---
>
> To return the AT-S84 management software to the default settings,  perform the following procedure:
>
> 1. From the Main Menu, type **T** to select **Switch Tools**.
>
>    The Switch Tools Configuration Menu is shown in Figure 11 on page
>      50.
> 2. From the Switch Tools Menu, type **R** to select **System Reboot** to start
>      the reboot.
>
>    The System Reboot menu is shown in Figure 12 on page 51.
> 3. Type **O** to select **Set Reboot Option**.
>
>    The following prompt is displayed:
>
>    ```
>    Select reboot option (F/I/N)>
>    ```
> 4. Type **F** or **I** to select one of the following:
>
>    **F** (Factory Default)
>
>    Resets all switch parameters to the factory default settings,
>      including IP address, subnet mask, and gateway address.
>
>    **I** (Reset to Defaults Except IP Address)
>
>    Resets all switch parameters to the factory default settings, but
>      retains the IP address, subnet mask, and gateway settings. If the
>      DHCP client is enabled, it remains enabled after this reset.
>
>    ---
>
>    **Note** Option **N** is described in “Rebooting the Switch” on page 50.
>
>    ---
> 5. Type **R** to select **Start Reboot Process**.
>
>    The following prompt is displayed:
>
>    ```
>    Are you sure you want to reboot the system (Y/N)>
>    ```
> 6. Type **Y** to start the reboot process.
>
>    The switch returns its operating parameters to the default values
>      and  begins to reload the AT-S84 management software. This process 
>      takes approximately one minute to complete. You can not manage the 
>      device during the reboot. After the reboot is finished, you can log
>      in  again if you want to continue to manage the device.

Comment: Ok thanks guess I will have to get adapter then. Found the software solution in the manual but no hardware one, so I thought maybe someone had the same switch and had found one. I guess it will be helpful for others searching how to reset the switch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to factory reset the switch without having login credentials.

1. Connect a console cable at 9600-N-8-1-P using a 'Cisco' type console cable.

- You may need to press  a few times to get a login.

2. At the "awplus login:" prompt, hold  and type "ati" (all lowercase, no quotes) and press .
3. You will be prompted about erasing the current start-up config. Type "y" and press .
4. You will be prompted once more that the erase is permanent. Type "y" and press .
5. The switch will throw some error messages and reboot.
6. At login, the switch will be at the default "manager : friend" login.